# PHP Radio Buttons - Keep The Values in The Form after an Error

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I'm building a contact page with email, name, etc. in HTML with PHP. I have radio buttons on my contact page as well. If the user submitted their name and checked a radio button but forgot to put an email in, the form processing page will flipped them back to the contact page with an error. I'm able to have my contact keep the values put in for their name (and email if user inputs it), but it does not keep the value checked in the radio button.

I'm new to PHP, so I bet it's a silly error on my part. Here's what I have for my Name Input:

```
Your Name:
<input type="text" name="name" <?php
    if (isset($form['name'])) {
        echo 'value="';
        echo htmlentities($form['name']);
        echo '"';
    }
?>/>
```

I tried to do something similar to my Radio. Here's what I have for my Radio:

```
Are you New to our Business?<br>
<input type="radio" name="customer" value ="yes" <?php
    if (isset($form['customer'])) {
        echo 'value="';
        echo htmlentities($form['customer']);
        echo '"';
    }
?>/>

Yes, I am!<br>
<input type="radio" name="customer" value="no"<?php
    if (isset($form['customer'])) {
        echo 'value="';
        echo htmlentities($form['customer']);
        echo '"';
    }
?>/>
No, I am a returning customer!
```

I'm storing the values on the user input in an array called $form - that's why I have ($form['name]). I would like to it to continue doing that. Some other responses I have researched simply have an isset without the array part.

Hopefully I've provided enough information... Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're right - sessions are better. I wrote this in just a regular form and have been working on switching it to sessions. That's why I have the $form. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
if (isset($form['customer']) && $form['customer'] == "yes") {
    echo 'checked="checked"';
}
```

and

```
if (isset($form['customer']) && $form['customer'] == "no") {
    echo 'checked="checked"';
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this helped a lot! I wanted to click the up arrow for you, but I need a reputation of 15 first. But know that I would if I could! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, even with low reputation you can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark underneath the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the if-conditional to the following:

```
<?php
    if (isset($form['customer']) && $form['customer'] == "yes") {
        echo 'checked';
    }
?>/>
```

Replace the "yes" with "no" for the No part.

Comment: Thanks so much - this helped a lot! I wanted to click the up arrow for you, but I need a reputation of 15 first. But know that I would if I could! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3281388: No worries, mate. Your thought is what matters. I am happy that I could be of some help.